# Rails EC2, Load balancer cannot get instance started

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-security-group, amazon-elb

I have looked all the issue but cannot find the issue as I'm working on https for rails on the EC2 so I have setup loading balance and security group, but it keep said instance is not working as it's mention 'OutOfService', i have look at the security group and all port is open

[image]

[image]
[image: one]

as it said Instance has failed at least the UnhealthyThreshold number of health checks consecutively. but when i open ip address from Ec2 dns address and it working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check availability zones of both load balancer and ec2 instance. If both are in different zones make sure that you enabled cross zone load balancing in the classic load balancer. Also make sure that the ping target is TCP:80 in the Health check of the load balancer.

Comment: Load balance and ec2 are using same availability Zones, VPC and subnet subnet-0eb0cb46, they are using  eu-west-1a and  i have tweak on TCP:80. Nothing happened